# writing test functions in terms of bump functions

Tags: real-analysis

Chose $\theta \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\theta(x)=1$ on a neighbourhood $U$ of $x=0$.

Let $\phi \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R})$ and consider the function $$\alpha(x):=\phi(x)-\phi(0)\theta(x).$$ Thus $\alpha(0)=0$ and $$\alpha(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\alpha'(t) dt=x \int_{0}^{1}\alpha'(sx)ds=x\int_{0}^{1}[\phi'(sx)-\phi(0)\theta'(sx)]ds:=x\beta(x).$$ So $$\phi(x)=\phi(0)\theta(x)+x\beta(x).$$ However $\beta \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}),$ because for $x \ne 0$ we have $$\beta(x)=\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)\theta(x)}{x}$$ and thus $\mbox{supp}\beta \subset  \mbox{supp}\,\phi\;  \cup  \mbox{supp}\, \theta:=K$, with $K$ compact.

It is right?

Comment: No. Why would you think the support of $\phi$ is contained in the support of $\theta?$

Comment: Sorry. I shouldn't think this.